# Unlink Function Not... Unlinking

Tags: php, file, fopen, unlink

So I have function that creates a file, exports data to it, lets the user download it, and then lets the user delete it. Everything works except for deleting it. I don't know if it's because the unlink function doesn't really work within a $_POST action or something else, but it'd be nice to know. I would just pass a variable to the header and have a script check for that variable in the header on load and then unlink the file from there as I've done that with success before, but the file name is dynamic, and the variables are lost when reloading the page, which the header always does (I suppose I could pass those variables you see through variables in the header, but I'd rather not if possible).

I wondered if those variables lost their value by this point in the script, but I know that can't be as they're just used a few lines before, and nothing is interrupting or changing them.

I also wondered about file permissions. I had to give _www permissions for the folder in order for the server to write to the folder, but I've checked permissions again, and _www (the server, apparently) has permissions to read, write, and execute. So it can't be permissions.

The die error does not display, either.

Lastly, I've tried removing those variables in the name of the file and just had fopen() create one with a static name and then tried to have unlink() delete it with the static name-- just to test to see if the variables changed or were lost for some reason-- but it still won't unlink with that static filename, either.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    unlink("exported-" .$result2 ."-alltime-" .$today .".csv") or die("Could not delete file! Oh noes!");
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified the file exists?

Comment: `exit(realpath($filename));`

Comment: As you mentioned; if the variables $result2 and $today are not set, you won't be able to generate the file name to delete. I'd start with echoing the file name to check if the file name is constructed properly

Comment: Yes, I already checked if the file exists (that's preliminary), and the variables $result2 and $today are indeed set. I removed the use of variables entirely just to eliminate that possibility, and it still doesn't unlink.

Comment: Permissions on the file?